# How to add a full stop to the end of a string, except if there is question mark, exclamation mark or semicolon?

Tags: javascript

This works for full stop only:

```
if (string.charAt(string.length-1) != ".") {
        string = string+".";
};
```

Comment: It's doing exactly as you coded it. Question marks, semi colons and asterisks are not the full stop (period) character. This has also nothing to do with regex

Comment: @daveL I need the full stop if there is not any of thoose mark.

Comment: But you haven't checked for the existence of those characters; just the absence of a full stop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add extra conditions into your 'if' statement to say "is not a . or a ? or a ! or a ;

Comment: Is it possible to make this by only one condition? Thank.

Comment: I don't personally thing it's worth a regex. your best option is the separate statements (it will be clearer to read)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the first character of a string.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str = "HELLO WORLD?";
if(str.charAt(str.length-1) != "." && str.charAt(str.length-1) != "?" && str.charAt(str.length-1) != "!" && str.charAt(str.length-1) != ";")
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str+".";
else
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For one condition, you could do this:

```
if(!~[".","!","?",";"].indexOf(string[string.length-1])) string+=".";
```

#### Explanation:

the tilde operator (`~`): `~x` is equivalent to `-Math.floor(x)-1`
 that means that if the last character isn't one of `[".","!","?",";"]`, indexOf returns -1,
 which the tilde operator changes to 0, which, when negated, gives true (because it is falsy)
 `!0 == false`

`string[x]` is equivalent to `string.charAt(x)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const addPeriodMark = (str) => {
  return str.endsWith(".") ? str : str + ".";
};
```

Use [endWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) for condition.